# MinGW error "undefined reference to 'typeof''"

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, linker-errors, c99

I get an "undefined reference to 'typeof'"-error compiling and linking this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main() {
    typeof(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Version of gcc is 4.3.3, command line is "gcc.exe -std=c99 1.c -o 1.exe".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By passing the option `-std=c99` to GCC you've asked it to compile according to the C99 standard, which doesn't support the `typeof` keyword.

You may want to use `-std=gnu99` instead.

Comment: Or use the alternate keyword `__typeof__`, which works regardless of standards compliance mode.